# Coding structure for an activitylist

Tags: php, structure

Following from [Way/coding method to do activitylist/log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892613/php-way-coding-method-to-do-activitylist-log)

I worked with the accepted answer on above question, by having two tables one for the descriptions of the activities, and other for the activities themselves..

```
table: activitylist
Columns:
id, description, date

table: activities
Column:
id, aID, uID, date
```

aID is activity id, uID is user id. activity id is the id in table ´activitylist´

I can now output:

```
person ate another persons apple
```

As this text is non-personal and can be used to all..

What if i would like to output:

```
Michael ate Peters apple
```

(example)

That will require to split up in the description/text?

I thought of that you would need to include the uIDs of Michael and Peter somewhere, but where? And how should i work with that splitted description?

I mean i cant make a row in table activitylist with description: "Michael ate Peters apple"
as im trying to make these descriptions universal so it could be Adam and Julia instaed of michael and peter..

Hope you understand, please comment if questions..

Update:
Conclusion:

**Theres a activity list that shows all activities done on the page, that all users can see. Then i wish to show an activity as "Mike has commented on Peters photo". How can i make an activity description when it includes users (this case: Mike, peter)**

Comment: You got an answer before I logged in again.

Comment: Hi, Karem.  Please do not put tags in your question titles; it just makes more work for us when we have to remove them.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another column to activities and call it uID2. Then in your description put something like '##UID1## commented on ##UID2##'s photo' then use str_replace to replace ##UID1## and ##UID2## like this:

```
$description = activitylist['description'];
$description = str_replace('##UID1##', $uid, $description);
$description = str_replace('##UID2##', $uid2, $description);
```

You'll of course have to query your database to replace the id with the name associated with that user id but that's the basic logic you could use with your current setup.

Comment: Please remove this answer and add as an comment if you want. I have updated my question maybe it helps to understand better, if not let me know

Comment: Nice thank you, did not thought of that at all! Great solution

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do something like that, I would have all of the varchars store strings which can be parsed by [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

```
$uid1 = 'Frank'; $uid2 = 'George';
$format = '%s ate %s\'s apple';
$ret = sprintf($format, $uid1, $uid2);
echo $ret; // Frank ate George's apple
```

Comment: cwallenpoole Hello. I have tried your solution too, but problem i found here was, in some cases the activity doesnt contain any $uid2, so i would need to do if else and then sprintf() instead of just str replace if #uid2# exists is in the activity description or not.. hope you understand